# Istio Envoy Filter Lua - Updating Response Body get stuck

Tags: lua, istio, envoyproxy

By following [envoy filter to intercept upstream response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67347469/envoy-filter-to-intercept-upstream-response) I was able to create envoy filter and it's partially working as well. I can see my https request is being interpreted by the envoy filter and can see the updated response getting printed in the logs.

However, in the Postman I am not getting response back and it is waiting indefinitely. The access logs shows the 400 response being logged. Wondering why the postman is not receiving the response body.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: test-http-filter
  namespace: test
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: istio
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: GATEWAY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            subfilter: 
              name: envoy.filters.http.router
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_AFTER  # INSER_BEFORE also tried
      value: 
       name: envoy.custom-resp
       typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua"
          inlineCode: |
            function envoy_on_response(response_handle) 
                  if response_handle:headers():get(":status") == "404" or response_handle:headers():get(":status") == "400" then
                    local body = response_handle:body()
                    local jsonString = tostring(body:getBytes(0, body:length()))
                    response_handle:logErr("Status: "..response_handle:headers():get(":status"))
                    response_handle:logErr("JSONString: "..jsonString)
                    jsonString = jsonString:gsub("mystring", "myUpdatedstring")
                    response_handle:body():setBytes(jsonString)
                  end
                end
```

Anyone experienced similar issue with `response_bandle:body():setBytes()` . The original post had `response_handle():set()` which is throwing error in my case.

Comment: Please check if the response has body.  Also check by passing the optional parameter always_wrap_body.  More details are in envoy documentation https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/lua_filter#body

Comment: yes. it has response body which I am storing in jsonString. I tried the always_wrap_body with both true and false. no change in behaviour

Comment: I am the author of the link answer. I was able to get it working with the exact config (except deployed in the istio-system namespace with the default workloadSelector of the ingress gateway) and the INSERT_BEFORE.
What are you trying to achieve? Have the rewrite on every request or just a special one? The namespace and the selector wouldn't work with the default config. Also the INSERT_AFTER shouldn't work, since `http.router` must be the last in the chain.

Comment: I would recommand to start with something simple, like `response_handle:headers():add("X-User-Header", "worked")` on every request. If that works, add the rest to find out if some of your code will break the filter.

Comment: thanks chris. you are right. insert_after isn't working. somehow while trying multiple values, i haven't noticed it. I tested the headers() by setting a dummy value. I can see the new header. Only the response body is not getting loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Please change patch operation from "operation: INSERT_AFTER" to "operation: INSERT_BEFORE" as the filter is getting applied after sending the response. Update the envoy filter as below

```
patch:
  operation: INSERT_BEFORE
```

Corrected the Envoy Filter

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: test-http-filter
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: GATEWAY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value: 
       name: envoy.lua
       typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua"
          inlineCode: |
            function envoy_on_response(response_handle) 
                  if response_handle:headers():get(":status") == "404" or response_handle:headers():get(":status") == "400" then
                    local body = response_handle:body()
                    local jsonString = tostring(body:getBytes(0, body:length()))
                    response_handle:logErr("Status: "..response_handle:headers():get(":status"))
                    response_handle:logErr("JSONString: "..jsonString)
                    jsonString = jsonString:gsub("mystring", "myUpdatedstring")
                    response_handle:body():setBytes(jsonString)
                  end
                end
```

Comment: I tried with this one. No change in behaviour. It's still the same.

Comment: Kindly remove sub filter and name attributes

Comment: Edited and Added the corrected EnvoyFilter yaml above.

Comment: I have removed subfilter. it's still the same.

Comment: The workloadSelector is wrong for the default istio installation. You need either `app: istio-ingressgateway` or `istio: ingressgateway`.

Comment: it's not default one. customised in the organisation, so i am using a selector according to the gateway pod label .

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal upvoting as that is an important change to make this work.